# Stripe subscriptions do not work whichever version of the api I use

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

Hi I am trying to change my payment method to use stripe. I am creating a plan and a customer and subscriptions for the customer using the code,

```
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("stripe api key");                                    
    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
      "name" => $randomString,
      "id" => $randomString,
      "interval" => "month",
      "currency" => "usd",
      "amount" => $amtincents,
    ));
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("stripe api key");                                    
    $cust = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
              "email" => $emailval,
            ));
    $custid = $cust->id;
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("stripe api key");                                    
    \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
      "customer" => $custid,
      "plan" => $randomString,
    ));
```

The plan and customer get created but no matter which version of the stripe api I use I get the error 'Method \Stripe\Subscription not found' when I try to subscribe the customer to the plan. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an older version of Stripe's PHP bindings. The `Subscription` methods were added in version [3.13.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3130-2016-05-04).

You should upgrade to the latest version (currently 4.3.0). You can download it from the repository: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases, or upgrade using Composer if you used it to install the library.